# Yielding concatenated lines with backslash but excluding comment blocks

Tags: python, generator

Currently trying to create a generator function that yield one file line at a time while ignoring comment blocks and concatenating lines with a backslash at the end with the following line. So for this block of text:

```
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line0>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line1># comment
<line2>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line3.1 \
line3.2 \
line3.3>
<line4.1 \
line4.2>
<line5># comment \
# more comment1 \
more comment2>
<line6>
# here's a comment line continued to the next line \
this line is part of the comment from the previous line
```

The ideal output would be:

```
<line0>
<line1>
<line2>
<line3.1 line3.2 line3.3>
<line4.1 line4.2>
<line5>
<line6>
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
try:
    file_name = open('path/to/file.txt', 'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File could not be found. Please check spelling of file name!")
    sys.exit()

#Read lines in file
Lines = file_name.read().splitlines()

class FileLineGen:
    def get_filelines(path: str) -> Iterator[str]:
        for line in Lines:
            #Exclude a line if it starts with #
            if line.startswith("#"):
                line.replace(line, "")
                continue
            if "#" in line:
                #Split at where the # is located
                line.split('#')
                #Yield everything before the comment block
                yield line.split('#')[0]
                continue
            if line.endswith('\\'):
                #Yield everything but the backslash
                line = line[:-1]
                yield line
                continue
            #Yield the line in all other cases
            else:
                yield line

    gen = get_filelines(file_name)
    for line in Lines:
        print(next(gen))
```

This produces the output of:

```
<line0>
<line1>
<line2>
<line3.1 
line3.2 
line3.3>
<line4.1 
line4.2>
<line5>
more comment2>
<line6>
this line is part of the comment from the previous line
```

So I've been able to remove the backslashes, but I've tried a variation of joins to no avail. Ideal logic would be to join the backslash with the next line first, so that if there's a # at the beginning of the line, then that line would be automatically excluded (and the trailing comments would not be included in the output).

Edit:
New output using with block in the FileLineGen class to open file:

```
    with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
        for line in my_generator(f):
            print(line)
```

```
<line0>

<line1>
<line2>

<line3.1 line3.2 line3.3>

<line4.1 line4.2>

<line5>
<line6>
```

Comment: You could use the built-in method re.sub, that way problem is reduced to replace a couple of string patterns and your code would be more simple, readable and with better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two operators, `#` and `\`. The latter has precedence over the former. That means you should check and process it first. Here is a simple way to do it using a list as a buffer to build up lines:

```
def my_generator(f):
    buffer = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line.endswith('\\'):
            buffer.append(line[:-1])
            continue
        line = ''.join(buffer) + line
        buffer = []
        if '#' in line:
            line = line[:line.index('#')]
        if line:
            yield line
```

The nice thing about wrapping an iterable of lines and using ducktyping is that you can pass in anything that behaves like a container of strings, not just a text file:

```
text = """# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line0>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line1># comment
<line2>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line3.1 \
line3.2 \
line3.3>
<line4.1 \
line4.2>
<line5># comment \
# more comment1 \
more comment2>
<line6>
# here's a comment line continued to the next line \
this line is part of the comment from the previous line'"""

for line in my_generator(text.splitlines()):
    print(line)
```

The result is as expected:

```
<line0>
<line1>
<line2>
<line3.1 line3.2 line3.3>
<line4.1 line4.2>
<line5>
<line6>
```

Another way to write that loop is

```
print('\n'.join(my_generator(text.splitlines())))
```

Comment: For some reason there aren't any spaces for the concatenated lines when I run your code, and when I use `line = ' '.join(linebuff) + line`, the space only appears after `<line3.1 ` and not the rest of the concatenated items

Comment: @JimT. The spaces are in the lines themselves, before the backslash, unless you are using different text. If you want the last space, you can do `' '.join(buffer) + ' ' + line`

Comment: I am using the same text - that piece of code does result in a space after each item in lines 3 and 4, but now there are also spaces placed before the start of every other line save for line 5. There's also a two-line space after line 2

Comment: @JimT. I don't know what to tell you. I copy-and-pasted the code directly into my editor, and then copy-and-pasted the results back. Are you modifying anything at all in the code, or typing it by hand?

Comment: The code hasn't been modified, I don't know if reading a file into Python versus having the text within the code makes a difference?

Comment: @JimT. How are you passing in the file? It shouldn't make any difference if you did it right and the file doesn't have weird stuff in it.

Comment: I'm passing in the file exactly as formatted in the original post with the try and except blocks.

Comment: @JimT. I highly recommend using a `with` block to read your file. Something like `with open(...) as f: for line in my_generator(f): print(line)` (with newlines and indentation after each colon). File objects are already iterable over lines. Perhaps doing `read().splitlines()` is doing something unexpected?

Comment: I think the slicing and the `rstrip` are the wrong way around in `line[:-1].rstrip()`. Also, the `rstrip` call should probably be `rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. You're absolutely right on the first count and arguably right on the second

Comment: @JimT. I fixed the bug pointed out by user. Let me know if that helps

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was able to get output without the spaces at the beginning of each line. However, there's now extra spaces after each line - please see my edits for the output I get now.

Comment: @JimT. See the latest. I think I fixed it for you

Comment: @MadPhysicist Current version of code results in vertical print of all characters in the console

Comment: @JimT. I just ran `with open('a.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(text)`. Then I did `with open('a.txt') as f: for line in my_generator(f): print(line)`. It worked as expected. Do you need to clear variables between runs or anything?

Comment: @MadPhysicist And now the expected result has printed! Thank you so much for your patience in working through this with me!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use the `re.sub` method.

```
def line_gen(text: str):

    text = re.sub(r"\s+\\\n", '', text)   # Remove any \ break
    text = re.sub(r"#(.*)\n", '\n', text) # Remove any comment
    # If the last line it is a comment it won't have a final \n.
    # We have to remove it as well.
    text = re.sub(r"#.*", '', text) 

    for line in text.rsplit():  # Using rsplit here we get ride of all unwanted spaces.
        yield line


with open("/tmp/data.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

    for line in line_gen(text):
        print(line)
```

**Content of data.txt**

```
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line0>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line1># comment
<line2>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line3.1 \
line3.2 \
line3.3>
<line4.1 \
line4.2>
<line5># comment \
# more comment1 \
more comment2>
<line6>
# here's a comment line continued to the next line \
this line is part of the comment from the previous line
```

**Result:**

```
<line0>
<line1>
<line2>
<line3.1line3.2line3.3>
<line4.1line4.2>
<line5>
<line6>
```

Comment: This solution also works tremendously well when the text is within the code, but not when I read in a file using `file_name = open(path/to/file.txt, 'r')` and then `Lines = file_name.read()`, passing in `Lines` instead of `text` in the function

Comment: @JimT. I'm beginning to suspect there's something wrong with your file. I can reproduce Raydel's result perfectly, but none of the problems you are having with both our solutions.

Comment: @JimT I adjust the solution for get the correct result when getting the text from a file.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda This is exactly the output that me and Mad Physicist were getting before, but ideally would like to have output for lines 3 and 4 be `<line3.1 line3.2 line3.3>` and `<line4.1 line4.2>` respectively

Comment: Fidgeting around with the regex...`\\\n` results in `<line3.1...` being printed vertically...is there a way to join() or simple `+ ' '` that space back on...?